# How do I pass ode45 an odefun that takes two arguments?

Tags: matlab

I have a use case as follows:

Inside `F.m` I have a function `F` that takes as its argument a `2 x 1` matrix `x`. `F` needs to matrix multiply the matrix `kmat` by `x`. `kmat` is a variable that is generated by a script.

So, what I did was set `kmat` to be global in the script:

```
global kmat;
kmat = rand(2);
```

In `F.m`:

```
function result = F(x)
    global kmat;
    result = kmat*x;
end
```

Then finally, in the script I have (`x_0` has already been defined as an appropriate `2 x 1` matrix, and `tstart` and `tend` are positive integers):

`xs = ode45(F, [tstart, tend], x_0);`

However, this is causing the error:

```
Error using F (line 3)
Not enough input arguments.

Error in script (line 12)
xs = ode45(F, [tstart, tend], x_0);
```

What is going on here, and what can I do to fix it? Alternatively, what is the right way to pass `kmat` to `F`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the proper way to handle `kmat` is to make it an input argument to `F.m`

```
function result = F(x,kmat)
    result = kmat*x;
end
```

Secondly, the input function to `ode45` must be a function with inputs `t` and `x` (possibly vectors, `t` is the dependent variable and `x` is the dependent). Since your `F` function doesn't have `t` as an input argument, and you have an extra parameter `kmat`, you have to make a small anonymous function when you call `ode45`

```
ode45(@(t,x) F(x,kmat),[tstart tend],x_0)
```

If your derivative function was `function result=derivative(t,x)`, then you simply do `ode45(@derivative,[tstart tend],x_0)` as Erik said.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `F` in `ode45(F,...)` should be a function handle, i.e. `@F`. Also, you can have a look at [this page of the MATLAB documentation](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/parameterizing-functions.html) for different methods to pass extra parameters to functions.